# how do you add files to existing programs

Tags: files, root, directory, system

How does the file system work with Ubuntu. How do you find where a program is and if needed how do you add file to it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. As it stands the question is not clear. Unlike Windows, programs in Ubuntu does not reside in a single folder. Various binary files live in various bin folders, while libraries required by the binaries live in various lib folders. Please clarify what you mean by adding a file to a program. Do you want to replace a part of a program file, or do you want to copy a data file (such as a document) used by a program?

Comment: Also see [Where should I put newly build software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63185/where-should-i-put-newly-build-software)

Answer (score 1):

For an overview of the linux file system see: http://lotphelp.com/lotp/tour-linux-filesystem

[image]

Normally you would "add" to your system by using the package manager, apt, using the graphical tool, software center.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

The ubuntu repositories are quite extensive and should have most everything you may need.

If there is something you need outside the repositories, you can manually add software via a number of techniques, most common is to compile it  manually. This should be avoided if possible.

For details on compiling see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

Answer (score 0):

As user68186 commented, Ubuntu programs have their files spread across multiple directories in the system. The package management system, called APT, manages the installation and maintenance of all these files seamlessly in day-to-day operation.

If you wanted to modify/add/remove files belonging to an installed package, the best way to do it is to actually rebuild that package from its source. If you just modify the installed files on your system, then the package management system will not be able to properly maintain it anymore.

You can list all the files that belong to a "package" using the `dpkg -L` command. For example, if you wanted to know about the `diffstat` command, you'd first ask what **package** that executable program belongs to, and then you could list the installed files belonging to that package:

```
$ dpkg -S $(which diffstat)
diffstat: /usr/bin/diffstat
$ dpkg -L diffstat
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/diffstat
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/diffstat.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/diffstat
/usr/share/doc/diffstat/copyright
/usr/share/doc/diffstat/README
/usr/share/doc/diffstat/changelog.Debian.gz
```